# No class 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy33' was registered - BadRequest on GAE endpoints

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

All of the sudden, previously working Google App Engine (JAVA) endpoint started to throw this at me:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No class 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy33' was registered",
    "reason" : "badRequest"
  } ],
  "message" : "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No class 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy33' was registered"
}
```

I'm executing endpoint method from android app like this:

```
CollectionResponseRPlayer response = endpoint.checkResult(gameId, answer, hash).execute();
```

`gameId` is `Long`, and the `answer` and `hash` are `Strings`

I stopped on `execute()` line to preview what values are passed in `gameId`, `answer` and `hash` to figure why could it be the bad request. They are as follows:

```
gameId = 8113932860298394396
answer = "KCMR"
hash = "D3C04148ACD9A166E6DBD0268D76AC39CB6C7CEB4B056522522B3551EA28830AFGF129DD89AB4CD6F7375526C796DE031450DF32611ACA1FEB904AB4ECCC3D7CD15CB267F38F10BAE1951RTBBDD3EC110005D67ED82FC5C8EF4E74FF5363D858AFCCAE4EF0A078FB550E833FD527B54"
```

As you can see, hash field is pretty long one. Could it be the reason?
I don't think it is. String in GAE is limited to 500 chars, and this hash barely 250. Also, I use the very same hash in every enpoint in may app, and this is the only one causing trouble...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Objectify. Problem was caused by:

```
ofy().save().entities(players, user);
```

Obviously I cannot provide collection and single entity at once, sot I fixed it with:

```
    ofy().save().entities(players);
    ofy().save().entity(user);
```

Comment: Hi! I am facing the very similar problem. I am also using Objectify to save the entities. I have create an Entity as: `@Entity
public class UserProfile {...}` but i don't see any Entity after running on the `http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin/datastore?`. Am i missing any step?

Comment: Also i am getting the same error while saving the Profile entity. `ObjectifyService.ofy().save().entity(profile).now();`